# Infinite Scroll wordpress not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to use the [Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) plugin for Wordpress. I set it up and it doesn't work.

Screen of settings:

[image: Screen settings screenshot]

**Template file**

```
<div id="posts-wrapper" class="row main">
<?php $counter = 1; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ){ while ( have_posts() ){ the_post(); ?>
    <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' ); ?>
    <div class="single-post <?php if( $counter == 5 ) { echo "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8"; } else { echo "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4";} ?>">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="category-wrapper"><?php the_category(', ');?></div>
            <a class="href-overlay" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="wrapper">
                <div class="<?php if( has_term( 'hot', 'hot', $post->ID ) ){ echo "inside inside-hot"; } else { echo "inside";} ?>"><div class="image-cover" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $url[0]; ?>)"></div></div>
            </div></a>
            <div class="post-wrapper">
                <p class="post-created-by">Napisane przez <strong><span class="special"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span></strong> | <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i> <?php comments_number( '0' , '1' , '%' ); ?></p>
                <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php $counter++ ; ?> 
<?php }else{ ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
</div>

<div id="paginacja">
    <?php next_posts_link('wczytaj więcej &raquo;')?>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any javascript error?

Comment: put a semicolon at the end of `$counter = 1` on second line

Comment: Also please let us know, what do u exactly mean by  **it doesn't work**

Comment: When I click on button it redirect me to 2nd page. It doesn't load more posts. And I don't got any javasript error

Comment: protip: don't? infinite scroll was briefly great when we first came up with it, then it turned out that pagination is actually far better because its behaviour is deterministic. Something that people actually like, as opposed to infinite scroll, which makes it impossible to ever find what you found last time, ever again.